# How can I configure zsh to let it explain to me where I can retrieve an executable instead of saying file not found?

Tags: zsh, command-not-found

In the default configuration of *bash* in *ubuntu*, when you type the
name of a software which is not installed, *bash* explains how to install it if 
the executable if it exists, or how to install an executable with a really close name if it does not exist.
For example with *emacs* (which is not installed on my machine):

```
$ emacx
No command 'emacx' found, did you mean:
 Command 'emacs' from package 'emacs23-lucid' (universe)
 Command 'emacs' from package 'e3' (universe)
 Command 'emacs' from package 'emacs23-nox' (main)
 Command 'emacs' from package 'emacs24' (main)
 Command 'emacs' from package 'emacs24-nox' (main)
 Command 'emacs' from package 'emacs23' (main)
 Command 'emacs' from package 'jove' (universe)
 Command 'emacs' from package 'emacs24-lucid' (universe)
emacx: command not found
$ emacs
The program 'emacs' can be found in the following packages:
 * emacs23
 * emacs23-nox
 * emacs24
 * emacs24-nox
 * e3
 * emacs23-lucid
 * emacs24-lucid
 * jove
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

With my current configuration of zsh I obtain:

```
$ emacx
zsh: command not found: emacx
$ emacs
zsh: command not found: emacs
```

There is also a difference of behavior when making a mistake in the name of an installed software.
Say I want to launch *gedit* instead of *kedit*. With *bash*, I obtain:

```
$ kedit
No command 'kedit' found, did you mean:
 Command 'xedit' from package 'x11-apps' (main)
 Command 'edit' from package 'mime-support' (main)
 Command 'nedit' from package 'nedit' (universe)
 Command 'gedit' from package 'gedit' (main)
 Command 'jedit' from package 'jedit' (universe)
 Command 'medit' from package 'medit' (universe)
 Command 'ledit' from package 'ledit' (main)
kedit: command not found
```

While with zsh I obtain:

```
$ kedit
zsh: correct 'kedit' to 'edit' [nyae]?
```

So, my questions are:

- Is it possible to have a similar behavior in *zsh* as with *bash* when trying to launch an executable not yet installed?
  If yes, how?
- Is it possible to display all the possibilities when there is a typing mistake, instead of giving 
  one correction which can be wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default zsh configuration for Debian (and probably Ubuntu) just doesn't include support for the `command-not-found` package per default.

In order to have the same functionality you just have to source `/etc/zsh_command_not_found` in your `~/.zshrc` per default via:

```
[ -f /etc/zsh_command_not_found ] && . /etc/zsh_command_not_found
```

This should load and enable the `command-not-found` functionality in `zsh`.

Comment: No dice here :(

Comment: Please Check https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/593804/206574

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to note that

```
[[ -e /etc/zsh_command_not_found ]] && source /etc/zsh_command_not_found
```

Is almost the correct answer. However, There is a little problem.

For some commands it returns absolutely no result. For Example try the following commands in bash:

```
$ muxy
muxy: command not found
$ mury
mury: command not found
```

But for zsh you will get NOTHING. No error message.

```
$ muxy
$ murez
```

Not to worry, the solution is in the `/etc/zsh_command_not_found` file.

```
if [[ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ]] ; then
    if (( ! ${+functions[command_not_found_handler]} )) ; then
        function command_not_found_handler {
            [[ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ]] || return 1
            /usr/lib/command-not-found --no-failure-msg -- ${1+"$1"} && :
        }
    fi
fi
```

Here the problem is with the `--no-failure-msg`. Remove it, and the problem will be solved.

What I do is, instead of using `[[ -e /etc/zsh_command_not_found ]] && source /etc/zsh_command_not_found`, I put the following lines in my .zshrc file.

```
if [[ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ]] ; then
    if (( ! ${+functions[command_not_found_handler]} )) ; then
        function command_not_found_handler {
            [[ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ]] || return 1
            /usr/lib/command-not-found -- ${1+"$1"} && :
        }
    fi
fi
```