# oh-my-zsh can't guess correct command

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

When I use bash in ubuntu and I type aa wrong command, it can guess for me, which correct common I could use:

bash:

```
haochen@ubuntu-dd:~$ aptget
No command 'aptget' found, did you mean:
 Command 'apt-get' from package 'apt' (main)
```

oh-my-zsh:

```
# haochen @ ubuntu-dd in ~ [9:13:14] C:100
$ aptget
zsh: command not found: aptget
```

Is there any settings that can enable this feature?

Comment: Remove OMZ: then Zsh will work correctly...

Comment: @jasonwryan, any way to not remove `omz`?

Comment: Why would you want to keep it? It turns a wonderful, modern shell into a bloated trainwreck.

Comment: @jasonwryan, I just want to ask this question and get feedback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable `command-not-found` plugin from `oh-my-zsh`

Refer to https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Plugins

Comment: nice, fixed, I only need this plugin

Comment: So wonderful it needs a plugin for [a one-liner](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65505/how-can-i-configure-zsh-to-let-it-explain-to-me-where-i-can-retrieve-an-executab)...

Comment: This didn't work for me.